# Viewing the Database for Android App?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am implementing extra features into an app, and I have been asked to add some more data into the database. My question is how do I view the database (SQLLite Database) within Eclipse or outside Eclipse and how would I add data into the database?

Thank You
(This is my first android project)

Comment: Do you have the database file?

Comment: They have provided me with the .sqlite and 2 .csv files

Comment: This seems a bit broad... you've been asked to "add data to a database" and you're asking us how to "add data to a database." That would mean we're doing your job? Have you tried google *at all*?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are lots of tools over the net where you can add and view data, but here are a few of them.

I usualy use a tool called [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/), pretty useful and allows to view and query database in a simple way.

For Eclipse there is a plugin called [Android SQLite Browser](https://code.google.com/p/android-sqlite-browser-for-eclipse/), also I used an [SQLite Manager plugin](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) for Eclipse a long time ago. If you are using Intellij IDEA, I can suggest using of [their database tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/database_tools.html).

Another popular one's are the [SQLiteManager](http://www.sqlabs.com/sqlitemanager.php) and [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/).